# How could i divide my layout in two parts in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to dive my layout in two parts that have common design.Layout orientation is horizontal and i want to have 2 layout of that layout how could i do that .Here is my XML please suggest me how could i do that.

Comment: "2 layout of that layout" means?

Comment: u need two linearlayout correct one by one..

Comment: @NareshR Like they are showing Airline,Deart,Arrival,Duration and Price i want to design that But i am not able to do that twice

Comment: @saravanan yup i am stucked in how to create this design i am new in android .Help me

Comment: Sure.. how can i help u.. give corrct details ma.

Comment: U put those two similar layouts in a horizontal layout ...

Comment: can u please post a rough sketch coz what u want is quite unclear from ur link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy and paste below code in your xml file, and made changes as you like,
You can ask for any help if you want

```
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_weight="1" >
    <Button 
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="461dp"
    android:layout_weight="1.00"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Button 
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You can add as many `Button` or any object where ever you want and with some more work you can make it as your link , as you have mentioned.

Comment: it's not working for me .If u can suggest me the changes as per my layout i will be thank full to u

Comment: it actually what i am looking for .but in my layout it is not setting up properly please help me in this

Comment: See there are many ways to achieve what you want, I would suggest you to do everything in `LinearLayout` as i have done, then provide weight  to child layout, and i dont think orientation in relative layout is a good idea,

Comment: thanks alot brother it worked for me.How could i put a line between the layout can u help me in  that.thanks

Comment: If it worked for you then click on acccepted , and for adding line try this
      <View
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"/>

Comment: where i have to do this ??

Comment: between the two layout two differentiate them

Comment: wherever you want , between any two objects,

Comment: like there is one main layout .in that we have two layouts i want between the two layouts

Comment: thanks alot for the help ..should i get u personal mail id so be in touch with u

Comment: can u help me on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18052890/use-scrollview-between-two-linear-layout-inside-a-linearlayout

Answer (score 0):

Take the references of layout objects at runtime using their id and depending upon requirement write condition in your code to show hide layouts.

Answer (score 0):

For instance I have just replicated the same views everywhere, don't mind it...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Make the root layout which is a `<RelativeLayout>` currently as `<LinearLayout>`.
2. Set the orientation of that linear layout to horizontal.
3. set `android:weight` of all the child layouts to '1'.
4. use `yourChildLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)` to show the two layouts which are needed and `yourChildLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE)` to hide the rest.