# Use scrollView between two Linear Layout inside a LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-scrollview

i want to put two scroll view on two layouts that are in inside a main layout .Here is my XML file Please help me on this

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/flightResultData"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/onewayflightLogo"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                android:src="@drawable/spicejet" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/onewayflightName"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="SpiceJet" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/onewayflightNumber"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="9W - 496" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/onewayflightTime"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:minLines="1"
                android:text="06:00 - 7:05"
                android:textSize="12dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/onewayflightDuration"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:minLines="1"
                android:text="1 Hour 35 Min"
                android:textSize="10dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/onewayflightstop"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:minLines="1"
                android:text="Non Stop"
                android:textSize="10dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/onewayflightAmount"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:minLines="1"
                android:text="Rs 200000"
                android:textSize="12dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/retrunflightLogo"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                android:src="@drawable/spicejet" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/retrunflightName"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="SpiceJet" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/retrunflightNumber"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="9W - 496" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/retrunflightTime"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:minLines="1"
                android:text="06:00 - 7:05"
                android:textSize="12dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/retrunflightDuration"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:minLines="1"
                android:text="1 Hour 35 Min"
                android:textSize="10dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/resturnflightstop"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:minLines="1"
                android:text="Non Stop"
                android:textSize="10dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/retrunflightAmount"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:minLines="1"
                android:text="Rs 200000"
                android:textSize="12dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

The View i am using to differentiate the two layouts i want those two layout in diffrent scroll view

Comment: you forgot to add scroll view in your layout

Comment: ya i know that i.e my question where i will the scroll view for the two different layout

Comment: Quite difficult to understand what you try to achieve here...  Maybe a little drawing would help ?  And be aware that it's resource consuming (and more often, useless) to use 3 or 4 nested LinearLayout like that.

Comment: @Guian will u help to create this layout in more simple way...i want that layout weight is 1 to be in a scroll view.Two layouts are there a that have weight 1 ..both of them i want in scrool view

Answer (score 0):

i think I have understood your issue . you want to separate two views laying two side of Bar with two different scrollView. If it is so then below is solution

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/flightResultData"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
     <ScrollView 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/onewayflightLogo"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                android:src="@drawable/spicejet" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/onewayflightName"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="SpiceJet" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/onewayflightNumber"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="9W - 496" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/onewayflightTime"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:minLines="1"
                android:text="06:00 - 7:05"
                android:textSize="12dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/onewayflightDuration"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:minLines="1"
                android:text="1 Hour 35 Min"
                android:textSize="10dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/onewayflightstop"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:minLines="1"
                android:text="Non Stop"
                android:textSize="10dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/onewayflightAmount"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:minLines="1"
                android:text="Rs 200000"
                android:textSize="12dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView> 
    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
   <ScrollView 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >



            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/retrunflightLogo"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                android:src="@drawable/spicejet" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/retrunflightName"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="SpiceJet" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/retrunflightNumber"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="9W - 496" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/retrunflightTime"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:minLines="1"
                android:text="06:00 - 7:05"
                android:textSize="12dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/retrunflightDuration"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:minLines="1"
                android:text="1 Hour 35 Min"
                android:textSize="10dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/resturnflightstop"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:minLines="1"
                android:text="Non Stop"
                android:textSize="10dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/retrunflightAmount"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:minLines="1"
                android:text="Rs 200000"
                android:textSize="12dp" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
   </LinearLayout>

   </LinearLayout>
```